# How to do a distinct query that returns multiple columns

Tags: ms-access

I need to create a MS Access query that will return only one instance of a serial number along with a few other columns.  For example

```
SerialNumber    CRM        EmailClient   VersionBuild  IPAddress  DateLogged
------------    ----       -----------   ------------  ---------  ----------
123456          Outlook    Outlook       4.7.4         0.0.0.0    20120625
123456          SugarCRM   SMTP          4.6.1         0.0.0.0    20120621
435352          ACT!       Outlook       4.5.2         0.0.0.0    20120619
537352          ACT!       SMTP          4.5.3         0.0.0.0    20120619
```

The results would be

```
SerialNumber    CRM        EmailClient   VersionBuild  IPAddress  DateLogged
------------    ----       -----------   ------------  ---------  ----------
123456          Outlook    Outlook       4.7.4         0.0.0.0    20120625
435352          ACT!       Outlook       4.5.2         0.0.0.0    20120619
537352          ACT!       SMTP          4.5.3         0.0.0.0    20120619
```

I was trying to complete this using the following query.  I think First and Group by cancel each other out.

```
SELECT FIRST(LogData.SerialNumber), LogData.CRM, LogData.EmailClient, LogData.VersionBuild, LogData.IPAddress, LogData.DateLogged
FROM LogData
GROUP BY  LogData.CRM, LogData.EmailClient, LogData.VersionBuild, LogData.IPAddress, LogData.DateLogged
```

Comment: Why does Frank Green not get returned for Serial 123456?  What determines who is first?

Comment: Frank Green does not get returned because it is the second result that has the same serial number as Bob Smith.  I am assuming that FIRST does this logic for me.

Comment: First is purely imaginary and depends on your sort order, one day it might be Bob, the next it could be Frank.

Comment: Great point!  In my real problem, this does not matter with the data that is being returned.

Comment: Hi Ryan, what is the primary key of your LogData table ?

Comment: I wish it had one.  This was designed and put together many many years before I got here.  I am just trying to get a query working for a coworker.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you mentioned LogData does not have a primary key.  If you add an autonumber primary key, your problem becomes very easy to solve.

Use a subquery to return a single `id` value for each `SerialNumber` group, and `INNER JOIN` the subquery to `LogData`.

```
SELECT base.*
FROM
    LogData AS base
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT SerialNumber, Min(id) AS which_id
        FROM LogData
        GROUP BY SerialNumber
    ) AS sub
    ON base.id = sub.which_id;
```

Replace `base.*` with a list of the fields you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this:

- get only one SerialNumber =>  GROUP BY SerialNumber
- get only one (the first) name for each SerialNumber =>  FIRST(LogData.First)

```
SELECT LogData.SerialNumber, FIRST(LogData.First), FIRST(LogData.Last)
FROM LogData
GROUP BY  LogData.SerialNumber
```

But be be warned: this could result (not in the case of the "FIRST"-function) a mixed record like:

```
Serial    First    Last
------    -----    ----
123456    Frank    Smith
```

By the way: The "FIRST"-Grouping-Function is not supported by all SQL-Systems:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html You may use another function to fulfill the sql-standard...

Comment: This query was fast and worked.  Anyway I can guarantee it will not be a mixed record ?

Comment: If you use MS-Access then there will be no mix of data for FIRST-Grouping-Function!

Answer (score 0):

This ain't pretty but...

```
SELECT L.SerialNumber, 
            (Select Top 1 A.First from LogData as A where A.SerialNumber = L.SerialNumber Order by A.First, A.Last) AS [First], 
            (Select Top 1 A.Last from LogData as A where A.SerialNumber = L.SerialNumber Order by A.First, A.Last) AS [Last]
FROM LogData AS L
GROUP BY L.SerialNumber;
```

Which is basically Thomas' answer, except that since you are using a subquery you can dictate the order by to make sure you always get the expected results.

Comment: http://paste2.org/p/2077464 This is what my actual sql query looks like.  When ran, I get the following message: At most one record can be returned by this subquery.

Comment: @Ryan, you really should provide accurate sample data, rather than letting people do this work and then tell them it does not suit your data.

Comment: @Remou -  I did not think adding 3 more columns to my example would have been a problem in solving this problem.  I updated my sample data  to more closely reflect my real life data.